# RecyclerView inside a ViewPager inside another RecyclerView not scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a user profile like Vine/Instagram. I have profile fragment and inside that I have a RecyclerView containing two different ViewHolders. One of them is the header (user's profile picture, username, etc.) and the other one is a TabLayout and ViewPager.

**ProfileAdapter.java**

```
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1;
private static final int TYPE_PAGER = 2;

private Context mContext;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

public ProfileAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_profile_header, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ProfileHeaderViewHolder(view);
    } else {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_profile_view_pager, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ProfileViewPagerViewHolder(view);
    }

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder instanceof ProfileHeaderViewHolder) {

    } else if (holder instanceof ProfileViewPagerViewHolder) {
        ((ProfileViewPagerViewHolder) holder).viewPager
                .setAdapter(new ProfileViewPagerViewHolder.ProfilePagerAdapter(mFragmentManager));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position == 0) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    } else {
        return TYPE_PAGER;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

**ProfileHeaderViewHolder.java**

```
public class ProfileHeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private CircleImageView profilePic;

private TextView nameText;
private TextView bioText;
private TextView urlText;

private TextView postsCountText;
private TextView followersCountText;
private TextView followingsCountText;

private TabLayout tabLayout;

public ProfileHeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    profilePic = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_profile_pic);
    nameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    urlText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_url);
    bioText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_bio);

    postsCountText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_posts);
    followersCountText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_followers);
    followingsCountText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_followings);
}
}
```

**ProfileViewPagerViewHolder.java**

```
public class ProfileViewPagerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TabLayout tabLayout;
public ViewPager viewPager;

public ProfileViewPagerViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vp_profile);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Posts"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Dares"));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

public static class ProfilePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ProfilePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                return new ProfilePostsFragment();

            case 1:
                return new ProfileDaresFragment();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a good way to obtain what I'm trying to achieve. I want the user to be able to switch between two options inside the user profile fragment.

**fragment_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_profile_view_pager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorGreyLight" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Most of what I've done so far seems to work and the only problem I'm encountering is that I can see the first item but I cannot scroll down further to see the remaining items in the rv_profile_posts RecyclerView.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

please set touch listener  on RecyclerView in this case

```
yourRecyclerview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why your using recyclerView?

> You can use the coordinatorLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">


        <!-- put your header widget here -->

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_1dp"
        android:background="@color/line_color" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin :

Faced the same issue, try adding this:-

`columnRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
   v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
   false
}`

this will disable the scrolling of your viewpager but enable recyclerview scroll.